# Как получить данные из DB и вывести в listview?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

Пример запроса из DB:

```
private class getValues extends AsyncTask {
//DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {


        // SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query("table",null, null, null, null, null, "name");
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                listItems.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, если вы хотите оставить комментарий автору ответа, так и делайте (нажав кнопку «добавить комментарий» под ответом). исправлять сам ответ для этого не стоит. если (как в вашем случае) комментарий содержит код, лучше текст комментария добавить в вопрос, а автору ответа написать об этом в комментарии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вам не надо закрывать курсор после его получения.
2. Вам надо определить тип возвращаемого значения из `doInBackground`
3. `Cursor` надо принять в `onPostExecute`
4. Там уже можно создать с ним адаптер и назначить его `ListView`, коий можно в `AsyncTask` передать через конструктор.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!!!

Comment: @ruslanab, если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, то вы можете проголосовать за него и отметить "верным", нажав на галочку слева от текста)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону ContentProvider + CursorLoader